# How to calculate a modulo of complex numbers?

Tags: python, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to find a way to do `(w+xi) % (y+zi)` in Python.

I have tried `cmath` but it doesn't seem to have support for this. I have made sure it is mathematically possible and attempted to program it, however it didn't work. The code is below, I found that the issue was sometime after dividing numbers would need to be rounded but at other times this produced an incorrect result.

```
def ComplexModulo(a,b):
       x = a/b
       x = round(x.real) + (round(x.imag)*1j)
       z = x*b
       return a-z
```

I need a better way to figure this out, as right now if I do `(8+2j)%(2+1j)` I should get `(1+1j)`, but I instead get `(-1+0j)`. I tried also changing `round` to `int`, and different combinations of that, and although it worked in some instances it failed in others.

Comment: It works different with complex numbers, and even still, the real part should not be minus 1. This explains what I am try to do https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-Modulo-of-complex-numbers

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(8%2B2i)%25(2%2B1i)) you get correct output.

Comment: Is this actually useful somewhere? Is it worth adding this to Python?

Comment: yes, it is useful and worth adding, although the uses for it are somewhat obscure, its worth it in my opinion given how simple it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct definition of the `modulo` operation involves using `floor` instead of `round`. You could find this in either `math` or `numpy` packages.

## EDIT

To expand a bit on *why* `round()` and `int()` do not work, it has to do with the rounding of course.

Let's consider an integer example:

```
5 / 3 = 1.6666...
5 // 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2

5 == 3 * 1 + 2
```

Now:

```
round(5 / 3) == 2 != 5 // 3
```

which will not give the correct result for the integer quotient of `5 / 3`.

On the other hand:

```
int(5 / 3) == 1 == 5 // 3
```

Would actually give the correct quotient in this case.

But if now consider:

```
-5 / 3 = -1.6666...
-5 // 3 = -2
-5 % 3 = 1

-5 == 3 * (-2) + 1
```

Then:

```
int(-5 / 3) == -1 != -5 // 3
```

and:

```
round(-5 / 3) == -2 == -5 // 3
```

and in this case `round()` would give the correct result and `int()` will not.

`floor()`, being defined as the largest integer smaller then the input, would work in both scenarios correctly.